# BufferedReader not closed warning not disappearing

Tags: java, eclipse, warnings, bufferedreader

I am using a BufferedReader, and though I call the close() method, eclipse still gives me a warning.
Eclipse does not give me a warning if I place the close() call before the while, but in then the code does not work.
Is there either an error in my code, or what else is the problem?
Code:

```
    Hashtable<String, Hashtable<String, Integer>> buildingStats = new Hashtable<String, Hashtable<String, Integer>>();
    try 
    {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("Assets/Setup/Buildings.txt"))); // Sets the buildings values to the values in Buildings.tx
        String line;
        int lineNum = 0;
        while((line = br.readLine()) != null)
        {
            ++lineNum;
            String[] values = line.split(",");
            if (values.length != 3)
                throw new Exception("Invalid data in Assets/Setup/Buildings.txt at line " + lineNum);
            if (buildingStats.containsKey(values[0]))
            {
                buildingStats.get(values[0]).put(values[1], Integer.parseInt(values[2]));
            }
            else 
            {
                buildingStats.put(values[0], new Hashtable<String, Integer>());
                buildingStats.get(values[0]).put(values[1], Integer.parseInt(values[2]));

            }

        }
        br.close();
    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return buildingStats;
```

Comment: Try putting br.close(); in a `finally` block

Comment: Gotta close in a finally. What if an exception is thrown before you reach that line?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should put it in a finally method like so:

```
BufferedReader br = null;
try {
    br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("Assets/Setup/Buildings.txt")));
    // do things
} catch (Exception e){
   //Handle exception
} finally {
    try {
        br.close();
    } catch (Exception e){}
}
```

If you still get the warning try cleaning and rebuilding your eclipse project.

Comment: It's a bad idea to swallow exceptions thrown by `close()`.

Comment: @LouisWasserman  I always think of it as, attempt to close, if you can't close its already closed or there is no way to close the connection.  Even if you call close again, you would get the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty much anything between the declaration and `close()` call can throw an exception, in which case your `close()` will not be called. Try putting it in a `finally` block.